# Compass and straightedge difficult construction

Tags: geometry

I don't know if there is any way to geometrically construct a circle with a given length of circumference.

I have tried several options but don't seem to get it.
Any construction I think of, involves π, which I think is impossible to construct geometrically, right?

Any help?

Comment: "Ruler" is the wrong word here.  Otherwise the answer is "use your ruler to find the length $1/2\pi$...  "Straightedge" is probably what you mean.

Comment: @B.Goddard, thank you, I edited the title.

Answer (score 2):

This construction is equivalent to squaring the circle, so there is no such construction:

> In 1882, the task was proven to be impossible, as a consequence of the
>   Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem which proves that $\pi$ is a
>   transcendental, rather than an algebraic irrational number; that is,
>   it is not the root of any polynomial with rational coefficients.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle

Answer (score 1):

cannot be done. $\pi$ is not just irrational, it is transcendental.

Comment: My friends who gave me the problem claim that it can be constructed because we don't need to calculate the exact value of the radius; just to construct it.

Comment: @PradeepSuny That's nice. If you wish to learn something, see http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf